# How to create a status bar icon for a vscode extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Thanks for the help, I would like to create a status bar button with a custom icon for my vscode extension. I have scoured documentation and code but none seems to work. The code so far.

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import "typescript";

let statusBar : vscode.StatusBarItem;

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    console.log("code-boilerplate is active!");
    
    const codeBoilerplate = vscode.commands.registerCommand('code-boilerplate.CodeBoilerPlate', () => {
    
        const documentFileType = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.languageId;
        const documentFileName = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.fileName;

        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Generating your Code Boilerplate... ⌛")
        if (documentFileType === "javascript") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "python") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "typescript") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "csharp") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "c") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "cpp") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "java") {
            return null;
        }
    });

    statusBar = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem(vscode.StatusBarAlignment.Right, 100);
    statusBar.command = codeBoilerplate;

    context.subscriptions.push(codeBoilerplate);
}

// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() {
    console.log("code-boilerplate is deactivated!");
}
```

The code is for a code boilerplate which generates a HelloWorld application when you click a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can include an icon in a `StatusBarItem` with:

`statusBarItem.text = "$(icon-name) some text";`

See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#StatusBarItem

Here are the available icons for use: [Product Icon Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels#icon-listing).

> The text to show for the entry. You can embed icons in the text by
> leveraging the syntax:
>
> My text $(icon-name) contains icons like $(icon-name) this one.
>
> Where the icon-name is taken from the ThemeIcon icon set, e.g.
> light-bulb, thumbsup, zap etc.

However, if you want a **custom** icon outside that `ThemeIcon` set, it doesn't look like that is supported: see [Support Custom Icons in Status Bar](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/72244).

---

Here is code to create **and show** a StatusBarItem:

```js
/**
 * Create and show a StatusBarItem
 */
function _showStatusBarItem() {

    sbItem = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem(vscode.StatusBarAlignment.Left, 1);
    sbItem.text = "someText";
    sbItem.tooltip = "Some tooltip text";
    sbItem.backgroundColor = new vscode.ThemeColor('statusBarItem.errorBackground');
    sbItem.command = "code-boilerplate.CodeBoilerPlate";
    sbItem.show();
}
```